# Laravel - multiple urls for one route

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, routes

cant find anything on this but im sure its simple.

I have a route that I need to duplicate 4 times as I use the url to change the query.

Currently:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
  $builds = Blog::findBuilds();
  return View::make('pages/home', compact('builds'));  
});
```

What I want to do is e.g.:

```
Route::get(array('/', '/trending', 'staff-picks'), function()
{
  $builds = Blog::findBuilds();
  return View::make('pages/home', compact('builds'));  
});
```

But that of course does not work. Whats the trick?

Answer (score 6):

As Laravelian's answer demonstrates you can and should use a dynamic route parameter. However if you just do

```
Route::get('{slug?}', function($slug = null){}
```

you will catch every request (except the ones that matches a route that was defined before this one)

To have more control use a regular expression:

```
Route::get('{slug?}', function($slug = 'index')
{
    $builds = Blog::findBuilds();
    return View::make('pages/home', compact('builds'));  
})->where('slug', '(trending|staff-picks)');
```

Now `slug` has to be either: *nothing* (because its an optional parameter `{...?}`) `trending` or `staff-picks`

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/{slug}', function($slug = null) {
    $builds = Blog::findBuilds($slug);
    return View::make('pages/home', compact('builds')); 
});
```

You're better off though, putting the function in a controller, and passing it this way:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'BlogController@getSlug');
Route::get('/', 'BlogController@getSlug');
```